# can not find spark path

Tags: php, codeigniter, ion-auth

I am new to codeigniter.I am trying to use a spark package called ion_auth.I created the following directory in my root directory

> ci
>
> -application
>
> -system
>
> -tools
>
> -sparks
>
> ----ion_auth
>
> --------2.5.0

in MY_Loader file i changed the spark path as the following

```
define('SPARKPATH', '../sparks/');
```

inside config/autoload.php i added the spark autoloader as the following

```
$autoload['sparks'] = array('ion_auth/2.5.0');
```

But whenever i try to implement it ,i am getting the error :

```
Cannot find spark path at ../sparks/ion_auth/2.5.0/
```

my code in controller is the following:

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        
        if($this->ion_auth->logged_in()==false){
            redirect('user/login');
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Use absolute path i.e. `define('SPARKPATH', FCPATH.'sparks/');`.

Comment: You can use files from [github repository](https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth). There is example controller so you can check practical use of Ion auth.

Comment: will it work with version 3?i am not sure...do people still use ion_auth?authentication in laravel is way too smarter

Comment: It can be seen that changes are pushed to fit CI3, last one yesterday.

Comment: Instead of using Sparks try the installation method on [this page](http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/)  Ion_auth works fine with CI v3.+